# How to access data returned from endpoint?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm trying to get the response from this api to get some leads, but the promise doesn't seem to finish and the browser stays on the loading page.

```
app.use(oAuth);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const someAPI = "https://www.oapis.com/crm/v2/Leads";

app.get("/", async  (req, res) => {
   
        const  {access_token} = req.oAuth
        
        const response = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: someAPI,
            headers: { Authorization: `oauthtoken ${access_token}`},

        });
        res.json(response.data);
    });
```

Any solution?
Tks!

Comment: Try adding error handling (i.e. a `try`/`catch` block)

Comment: I tried it and no error appears, but it just doesn't return the api data;

Comment: have you tried running the request using CURL / postman / whatever you use to test your API? Does it respond? Have you written the API endpoint? If yes, does the response check for user agent or similar stuff ?

Comment: yes, in postman it returns all the data in the body, all right. I'm using the same endpoint and parameters in vs code, but using axios and express.js.

Comment: I'm using a middleware (app.use(oAuth)) to get the access token. After that I'm inserting the token into the axios call. In the end the code doesn't have any errors, it just doesn't return the data in the browser or in the console. It looks like the promise is unresolved. am I right?

Comment: @GabrielDillenburg Try adding a [`timeout`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config). Also please [edit] the question to show us your updated code with the error handling and the console logging. Also did you check that the endpoint handler even runs, and that you can normally return a response (without the oapi call)?

Comment: guys, tks for now, but I find the problem. Please follow this link to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930050/destructuring-assignment-object-from-a-middleware-response

Answer (score 1):

For calling API's or doing async work
Use **then**

```
await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: someAPI,
            headers: { Authorization: `oauthtoken ${access_token}`},

        }).then(resData=>console.log(resData)).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Here I have just consoled logged the response, you can do whatever you want with it
I hope this fixes your issue