# Destructuring assignment object from a middleware response

Tags: node.js, post, axios, destructuring, object-destructuring

I created a middleware as below:

```
const oAuth = (req, res, next) => {

    axios.post(tokenEndpoint, "", { params: {

        grant_type: process.env.GRANT_TYPE,
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        code: process.env.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
       
    
    }}).then(response => {
        req.oAuth = response.data;
        //console.log(response.data);
        console.log(req.oAuth);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
    next();
}

module.exports = oAuth;
```

the response/result of the oauth function is something like:

```
{
  access_token: '1000.ddf6d96b4f3sadasdasdas55a2450ae13',
  refresh_token: '100dasdsadasdsadhgdhgfhdghdfghe427288',
  api_domain: 'https://www.oapis.com',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3600
}
```

now in the "index.js" file I'm trying to destructure the oAuth function response object to access the attribute **access_token** and put it in the URL to make a post request, but I'm not succeeding. what am I doing wrong?

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const oAuth = require("./oAuth.js");

const app = express();

app.use(oAuth);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const someAPI = "https://www.oapis.com/crm/v2/Leads";

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
   
    try {
        const {access_token} = req.oAuth
                
        
        const response = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: someAPI,
            //timeout: 1000,
            headers: { Authorization: `Zoho-oauthtoken ${access_token}` },

        });
        return res.json(response.data);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          res.status(401).json("Unauthorized to access data");
        } else if (error.response.status === 403) {
          res.status(403).json("Permission denied");
        } else {
          res.status(500).json("Whoops. Something went wrong");
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: The problem is not with your destructuring assignment, but rather simply that your middleware never calls `next`.

Comment: @bergi I did it and it still didn't work.

Comment: You are receiving response after the next is called, thus `oAuth` is not available in your handler. One way of doing this can be waiting for response of the http call you are making in your middleware.

Comment: @GabrielDillenburg But you did it in the wrong place. You must only call `next()` once you amended the request, and if you received an error you should call `next(error)`.

Comment: @holymoof I see. would you be able to give an example using this code?tks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using async/await here to wait for oauth response and only then modify request object in order to pass it further to the `next()` callback.

```
const oAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const response = axios.post(tokenEndpoint, "", { params: {
            grant_type: process.env.GRANT_TYPE,
            client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
            code: process.env.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,    
        }});
        console.log(response.data);
        req.oAuth = response.data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    next();
}

module.exports = oAuth;
```

Comment: thanks, but now I'm getting  this response when the middleware is called in the index.js file: { error: 'invalid_code'}.
 
Iis this syntax correct? const {access_token} = req.oAuth

Comment: when I manually put the access_token obtained from the "oAuth" function in the url parameter, it works. Seems like a problem accessing the function's response object attribute, right?

Comment: @GabrielDillenburg I've edited the answer and removed `req` being passed to `next()` callback. What do you get when trying to access  `req.oAuth` in the index.js file?